# Solving Stochastic Differential Equation for Geometric Brownian Motion with time-dependent drift

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, itos-lemma

Given the stochastic differential equation:

$$dZ_t = -Z_t \theta_t dB_t, \quad Z_0 = 1.$$

for an adapted process $\theta_t$ and Brownian motion $B_t$, how exactly do I apply Itô's Lemma to obtain:

$$
Z_t = \exp\left(- \int_{0}^{t}\theta_u \;dB_u - \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{t}\theta_u^2 \;du\right)?
$$

Comment: Use Ito's lemma to find an expression for $d \ln Z_t$ and then solve that SDE.

Answer (score 5):

This is the SDE for a geometric Brownian motion with time dependent volatility $\theta_t$.
It can be easily solved with the substitution 
$$
X_t =  \log Z_t =: f(Z_t).
$$

According to Ito's Lemma we have that 
\begin{align}
 dX_t &= d f(Z_t) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}(Z_t) \;d Z_t + \frac 12 \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial z^2}(Z_t) \;\bigl(dZ_t \bigr)^2 = \\[2mm] 
&= -\frac{1}{Z_t} Z_t \theta_t \; dB_t - \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{\bigl(Z_t\bigr)^2} \bigl(Z_t \theta_t\bigr)^2 \; dt = \\[2mm]
&=-\theta_t \; dB_t - \frac 12 \theta_t^2 \; dt. 
\end{align}

Therefore, 
$$
X_t = X_0 - \int_0^t \theta_u \; dB_u  - \frac 12 \int_0^t \theta_u^2 \; du,
$$
and the result follows by simply applying $\exp$ to both sides.